# SQL Server inserting into multiple foreign keys within one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys

So I am fairly new to SQL, currently learning and just messing around at the moment making a basic database to practice optimization/efficient functions etc. I have 3 tables within the database, one of the tables contains 2 foreign keys referenced to the other 2 tables in the database. I am not sure how to `INSERT SELECT` into these columns at the same time as they are both `NOT NULL`. I understand I can design the database a different way but I am pretty sure its possible so I would like to figure it out. Here are the `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
CREATE TABLE engine_info
(
    e_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    e_year DATE NOT NULL,
    e_mark NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    e_size DECIMAL(1,1) NOT NULL,
    e_gearbox NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    e_gearratio DECIMAL(5,5) NULL,
    e_power INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_einfo PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc1_einfo 
    ON engine_info(e_year, e_mark, e_size, e_power);

CREATE TABLE chassis_info
(
    c_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    suspension NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    axle_size NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    caliper_size NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    disk_size NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_cinfo PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc1_cinfo 
    ON chassis_info(caliper_size, disk_size);

CREATE TABLE manufacturer
(
    m_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    manufacturer NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    model NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    e_id INT NOT NULL,
    c_id INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_minfo PRIMARY KEY (m_id),

    CONSTRAINT fk1_minfo FOREIGN KEY (e_id)
        REFERENCES engine_info (e_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk2_minfo FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
        REFERENCES chassis_info (c_id)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc1_minfo 
    ON manufacturer(manufacturer, model);
GO
```

Comment: First, insert engine_info rows then chassis_info rows (or vice versa). However, I think your schema is missing a `model` table. You need a `model` table with PK( `manufacturer_id`, `model_id`).  Each model of car would be defined by a combination of `e_id` and `c_id` (engine & chassis). Your foreign key constraints would be moved to the `model` table.

Comment: How are you doing the select? I mean, who do you know what engine to select and what chassis to select *before* you insert the manufacturer?

Comment: If you can't insert a NULL in a field then just insert a default value like for example 0. And if it's a foreign key then make sure that default value is the other table.

Comment: Can be done in the DLL of the table. For example `e_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Comment: seems all too obvious now, thanks guys appreciated!